# How to generate idempotency token for remote cache

Tags: java, concurrency, caching

We are using a client library over Memcache.
This library has a lot of logic for Memcache client and is indispensable in current form.
One of the API of the library is `put` which internally just uses an async mechanism to write to Memcache. There is no way to know if the `put` actually went through.

Changing the library is not feasible currently because it is owned by a different team and would take its time.

I was thinking of adding a behavior in my application to know with surity that any `put` calls actually went through or not.
Given that the same key can be written concurrently from other hosts, i was thinking if there is a way where i can generate an idempotency token that is persisted in the cache item itself and post `put`, do a `get` and check for the token.

So the sequence is:

```
Token t = "UUID";

put(keyWithToken, val);

while(timeLeft()){
   Item i = get(keyWithToken);
   if(i.get("token").contains(t)) {
      break;
   }
}
return null;
```

Does that sound right? If yes, do I need to have a list for idempotency token OR is there some single number field can solve it too?
Note that i can't simply use a `version` field as this could be written by other host too.

Comment: I'm a little unclear about the problem. Do you expect your application will write to memcache using the same key as another application? What do you mean by "another host"?

Comment: Yeah thats correct, so there could be more than 1 writers to same key concurrently

Comment: So, the *real* problem is preventing concurrent writes to the same key. What is the problem with concurrent writes to the same key?

Comment: Are the writes coming from the same application, but different instances of the application?

Comment: Memcache `add` works only if the key doesn't exist. Basically if `add` returns `false` you know the key already exists and its value has not been replaced. If you use `add` instead of  `set` you don't have to add boiled plate code to your source code.

Comment: The library is a generic one and it swallows memcache specific behaviour.
You can assume the only signature it exposes is:
```
void put(byte[] key, byte[] value, int ttl);
```

Comment: @GregBurghardt The writes are coming from different instances of same application

Comment: And what is the consequence of allowing competing write operations?